# Chrome: How to get backtrace of network calls

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When working with other peoples code, I often find my self hunting for what is making a specific network call. If I hover over the initiator column in network, then a little tooltip shows up showing the stack trace with a scrollbar to show all the stacktrace... but as soon as I move my mouse out of the initiator cell the popup tooltip leaves.

So the data is there, but I can't get to it. How can I get to that stack trace?
These ajax calls are better at hide and seek than me :\